# How to read a pointer to integer pointers from a file?

Tags: c, pointers

I wanted to read a pointer to integer pointers from a file.

I am using the following code to write to file:

```
FILE *fp;
int **myArray = NULL;
int i, j;

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    myArray = (int **)realloc(myArray, (i+1)*sizeof(int *));
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        myArray[i] = (int *)realloc(myArray[i], (j+1)*sizeof(int));
        myArray[i][j] = i*j*10;
    }
}

if((fp=fopen("test", "wb"))==NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open file.\n");
}
if(fwrite(myArray, sizeof(int), 3*4, fp) != 12)
    printf("File write error.");
fclose(fp);
```

I am using the following code to read, but I get a seg-fault while running it.

```
FILE *fp;
int **myArray = NULL;
int i, j;

for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    myArray = (int **)realloc(myArray, (i+1)*sizeof(int *));
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        myArray[i] = (int *)realloc(myArray[i], (j+1)*sizeof(int));
    }
}

if((fp=fopen("test", "rb"))==NULL) {
    printf("Cannot open file.\n");
}

if(fread(myArray, sizeof(int), 3*4, fp) != 12) {
    if(feof(fp))
        printf("Premature end of file.");
    else
        printf("File read error.");
}

for(i=0; i < 3; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < 4; j++){
        printf("%d\n", myArray[i][j]);
    }
}

fclose(fp);
```

**EDIT:** On more thorough debugging, I found that `fread` function is making the memory allocated for `myArray` invalid. Any ideas on what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: You are most definitely *not* reading a "pointer to pointer". What you have is a two-dimensional *array* (which you may or may not handle via pointers).

Comment: @KerrekSB Apologies. I was in the process of posting the entire question. Had submitted it earlier by mistake.

Comment: @KerrekSB Moreover, I may be wrong but isn't this a pointer to pointer to an `int`? Of course, it behaves like a 2D array in most cases but it isn't exactly one.

Comment: No problem. No, pointers and arrays are very different things. They're related, but quite different.

Comment: It builds and runs fine with me. What are you doing between the writing and the reading? How, when and where are you `free`'ing `myArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very unusual to read a pointer (to anything, including integer pointers) from a file. This is unusual because the information in files remains after your program finishes running, but any pointer is deallocated by the operating system when your program finishes.

So i assume you actually want to write (and read) some useful data (integers in your case), and not pointers - and your writing code is bad:

> fwrite(myArray, sizeof(int), 3*4, fp)

Use a loop to write the data instead of pointers:

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    fwrite(myArray[i], sizeof(int), 4, fp);
}
```

Then, use a similar loop to read the data:

```
for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    fread(myArray[i], sizeof(int), 4, fp);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `putc()`:

```
char ch;
FILE *input, *output;
input = fopen( "tmp.c", "r" );
output = fopen( "tmpCopy.c", "w" );
ch = getc( input );
while( ch != EOF ) {
  putc( ch, output );
  ch = getc( input );
}
fclose( input );
fclose( output );
```

Now replace `*input` by your `int` matrix. If you are getting a `segfault`, it's most likely you are not allocating the memory correctly. Left as exercise for you.

Comment: Thanks, is there anything particularly wrong with using `fwrite\fread`?

Comment: @stressed_geek No, nothing wrong ... but sounds more natural when you are inserting a `int` each time. You can also create a string in the line format you want to output, and then `fwrite\fread` would make more sense.

Comment: @stressed_geek Also, could you accept my answer if it solved your problem? Therefore, other people can use it as base later.